# Are symbolic indexing possible in matlab?

Tags: matlab, indexing, symbols

I have such a function `lnn1c(ii, j, n, n1)` which takes indexes `ii` and `jj` as arguments where `Kdk1` and `Wdg` are some arrays, `wg(n)` is another function kinda `alpha*(n-3)` and `Gdg` is a symbolic variable.

```
function lnn1c=lnn1c(ii, j, n, n1)
    syms k1Vzdg
    global Gdg Wdg Kdk1
    lnn1c=Gdg-i*(-(Wdg(ii)-Wdg(j))+(wg(n)-wg(n1))+...
        (Kdk1(ii)-Kdk1(j))*k1Vzdg);
end
```

I wanna perform in my script summation  of expression `lnn1c(ii, j, n, n1)` over indexes `ii` and `j` from 1 up to 4.
I tried such code

```
syms ii jj n n1
sum(subs(sum(subs(lnn1c(ii, jj, n, n1), ii, 1:4)),jj, 1:4))
```

but I keep getting such error

> Indexing input must be numeric, logical or ':'.

Any help would be really valuable for me.

Comment: Note: creating symbolic variables that will be returned and globals *inside* a function is a terrible idea. All hints that you need to rewrite your code in a smarter way or you'll find more problems. Also note that as `i` is the imaginary unit, so its `j`. Writing `ii` to avoid it, but then writing `j`  doesnt solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, symbolic indexing makes no sense.

However, you may be mixing ideas. You are effectively doing `subs(f(ii, jj, n, n1), ii, 1:4)`. You put `ii` and then substitute it by 1:4. Why not put `1:4` as input?

Just do:

```
for jj=1:4
    s=s+sum(lnn1c(1:4, jj, n, n1));
end
```

Surely you will need numeric values for `n` and `n1`.... 
As you haven't shown the whole code, its hard to know what you are doing, but there are hints to say that you do not need symbolic maths at all and you are just mixing programming concepts.

Answer (score 0):

As Ander points out, you can do it in two for loops and you'll have no problem:

```
s=0;
for jj=1:4
    for ii=1:4
    s=s+sum(lnn1c(ii, jj, n, n1));
    end
end
```

However, if your intention is to do it in 1 line, why don't you try arrayfun?

```
s=sum(arrayfun(@(ii) sum(arrayfun(@(jj) lnn1c(ii, jj, n, n1),1:4),1:4));
```

And no need for syms ;)

Comment: your one solution doesn't work. It throws an error:
 Error using arrayfun
sym output type is not currently
implemented.