# How can we put element of vector to symsum?

Tags: matlab, vector, series

I am trying to use `symsum` using Matlab. But I get a strange error.

I am trying to put elements of a vector into `symsum`:

```
a=[1,2,3,40,51,61];

syms u n 

S1(u) = symsum((a(n+1)*(-u)^n)/factorial(n),n,[0,6])
```

Error is:

> Invalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that the arguments are symbolic variables and the body of the function is a SYM expression. When indexing, the input must be numeric, logical, or ':'.

Answer (score 1):

First, I can see a mistake where you write `a(n+1)`, for `n` going from `0` to `6`. When `n` equals `6`, you will have `a(7)` which doesn't exist. `a` only has 6 elements.

Then, you have another problem because you are indexing `a` with a symbol, and symbolic indexing is not allowed (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42295300/7105378)).

Does `n` really need to be a symbol and do you really need to use `symsum`? If not, you can try:

```
a = [1,2,3,40,51,61];
n = 0:5; 
syms u
    S1(u) = sum( sym( (a(n+1).*(-u).^n)./factorial(n) ) )
```

This returns:

```
S1(u) =

- (61*u^5)/120 + (17*u^4)/8 - (20*u^3)/3 + (3*u^2)/2 - 2*u + 1
```