# Error while evaluating the function convolution

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

This is my first attempt to write anything in matlab, so please, be patient.

I am trying to evaluate the solution of the following ODE: w'' + N(w, w') = f(t) with the Cauchy conditions w(0) = w'(0) = 0. Here N is a given nonlinear function, f is a given source. I also need the function

[image]

where G is the solution of the following ODE:

[image]

where G(0) = G'(0) =0, `s` is a constant, and

[image]

My try is as follows: I define `N`, `f`, `w` and `G`:

```
k = 1000;
N = @(g1,g2) g1^2 + sin(g2);
f = @(t) 0.5 * (1 + tanh(k * t));

t = linspace(0, 10, 100);
w = nonlinearnonhom(N, f);
G = nonlinearGreen(N);
```

This part is ok. I can plot both `w` and `G`: both seems to be correct. Now, I want to evaluate `wG`. For that purpose, I use the direct and inverse Laplace transforms as follows:

```
wG = ilaplace(laplace(G, t, s) * laplace(f, t, s), s, t);
```

but is says

```
Undefined function 'laplace' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in main (line 13)
wG = ilaplace(laplace(G, t, s) * laplace(f, t, s), s, t);
```

Now, I am not sure if this definition of `wG` is correct at all and if there are not any other definitions.

**Appendix:** `nonlinearGreen(N)` is defined as follows:

```
function G = nonlinearGreen(N)

eps = .0001;
del = @(t)[1/(eps * pi) * exp( -t^2/eps^2)];

eqGreen = @(t, g)[g(2); - N(g(1),g(2)) + del(t)];
tspan = [0, 100];
Cc = [0, 0];
solGreen = ode45(eqGreen, tspan, Cc);
t = linspace(0, 10, 1000);
G = deval(solGreen, t, 1);

end
```

and `nonlinearnonhom` is defined as follows:

```
function w = nonlinearnonhom(N, f)

eqnonhom = @(t, g)[g(2); - N(g(1),g(2)) + f(t)];
tspan = [0, 100];
Cc = [0, 0];
solnonhom = ode45(eqnonhom, tspan, Cc);
t = linspace(0, 10, 100);
w = deval(solnonhom, t, 1);

end
```

Comment: Hi, please maintain the question with **minimal** code, if you change some parts, remove the old ones. If it's not about convolution anymore, update the title of your question. Also, include the whole error message of matlab (the line numbers). But I suspect that you try to index an array with a symbol which is [forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295215/are-symbolic-indexing-possible-in-matlab).

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I left only the codes for evaluating `G` and `w` just in case if someone wants to run the whole program.

Comment: I want to plot `w` and `wG` fot 0 < t < 10.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of problems in one. You need to apply the *Divide and Conquer* strategy and split your problem in different smaller problems easier to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep mixing different kind of types and it's not a good idea. I suggest you keep with symbolic all the way if you want to use the `laplace` function. When you define `N` and `f` with `@`(arobase) as `function handles` and not `symbolic expressions` as you might want to do. I suggest you have a look at [`symbolic`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) documentation and rewrite your functions as symbolic.

Then, the error message is pretty clear.

> Undefined function 'laplace' for input arguments of type 'double'.
>   Error in main (line 13)
>   wG = ilaplace(laplace(G, t, s) * laplace(f, t, s), s, t);

It means that the function `laplace` can't have arguments of type `double`.

The problem is that your `t` is a vector of `double`. Another mistake is that `s` is not defined in your code.

According to Matlab documentation of [`laplace`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/laplace.html), all arguments are of type `symbolic`.

You can try to manually specify symbolic `s` and `t`.

```
% t = linspace(0, 10, 100); % This is wrong
syms s t
wG = ilaplace(laplace(G, t, s) * laplace(f, t, s), s, t);
```

I have no error after that.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications. I now want to plot `w` and `wG` on the same figure. I guess, I need to use `fplot(@(t) wG, [0 10])`, but it does not work.

Comment: It's because the code needs significant change for plotting or I have chosen a wrong section for this question?