# Error while plotting the convolution of two functions

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to plot two functions on the same figure. One is the solution of a nonlinear ODE, while the other one is the convolution of two functions. See the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530572/error-while-evaluating-the-function-convolution).

I run

```
k = 1000;
N = @(g1,g2) g1^2 + sin(g2);
f = @(t) 0.5 * (1 + tanh(k * t));

w = nonlinearnonhom(N, f);

syms s t
G = nonlinearGreen(N);
wG = ilaplace(laplace(G, t, s) * laplace(f, t, s), s, t);
```

but

```
fplot(@(t) wG, [0 10])
```

gives a warning like

```
Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve performance, properly vectorize
your function to return an output with the same size and shape as the input arguments.
```

and plots `wG = 0`.

Any suggestion or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Define "does not work". Does it error, does it generate a wrong plot? Does it make your computer explode...

Comment: `wG` is an array of syms that contains 1000 elements. You may have a problem in asking too much plot all at once.

Comment: And `properly vectorize your function` would help, right? But how to do that?

Comment: `wG` are symbolic expressions of two variables (`s`, and `t`) and I don't think it can be plotted with `fplot`.

Comment: `wG` should depend only on `t`. `laplace(G, t, s)` depends on `s` and `ilaplace(laplace(G, t, s), s, t) = G` depends only on `t`.